# vagrant provisining don't work on Windows but work on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vagrant, puppet

I have vagrant/puppet provision script and see there is a problem when my host machine is Windows (when hosting on Ubuntu doesn't seems to have this problem). I can see that apache::concat working with apache ports.conf file have a problem. I'm using guest box same on both places (ubuntu server 14.04). As far as I know puppet is running on guest machine.

My question is why I have this warnings and errors during provisioning?

```
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Notice: Compiled catalog for eclectic.vm in environment production in 7.06 seconds
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[apt-update]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[git-checkout-drush]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/var/www/vhosts/eclectic.ca]/mode: mode changed '0777' to '0775'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ca.eclectic.vm]/File[/var/www/vhosts/eclectic.ca/public_html]/owner: owner changed 'www-data' to 'root'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ca.eclectic.vm]/File[/var/www/vhosts/eclectic.ca/public_html]/group: group changed 'vagrant' to 'root'
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Apache/Concat[/etc/apache2/ports.conf]/Exec[concat_/etc/apache2/ports.conf]: Could not evaluate: /usr/bin/env: ruby
: No such file or directory
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache/Concat[/etc/apache2/ports.conf]/File[/etc/apache2/ports.conf]: Dependency Exec[concat_/etc/apache2/ports.conf] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Apache/Concat[/etc/apache2/ports.conf]/File[/etc/apache2/ports.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[composer-install-drush]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ssl-ca.eclectic.vm]/Concat[25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]/Exec[concat_25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]: Could not evaluate: /usr/bin/env: ruby
: No such file or directory
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ssl-ca.eclectic.vm]/Concat[25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]/File[25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]: Dependency Exec[concat_25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ssl-ca.eclectic.vm]/Concat[25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]/File[25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ssl-ca.eclectic.vm]/File[25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf symlink]: Dependency Exec[concat_25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ssl-ca.eclectic.vm]/File[25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf symlink]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ca.eclectic.vm]/Concat[25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]/Exec[concat_25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]: Could not evaluate: /usr/bin/env: ruby
: No such file or directory
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ca.eclectic.vm]/Concat[25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]/File[25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]: Dependency Exec[concat_25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ca.eclectic.vm]/Concat[25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]/File[25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ca.eclectic.vm]/File[25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf symlink]: Dependency Exec[concat_25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Main/Apache::Vhost[ca.eclectic.vm]/File[25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf symlink]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Dependency Exec[concat_/etc/apache2/ports.conf] has failures: true
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Dependency Exec[concat_25-ca.eclectic.vm.conf] has failures: true
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Dependency Exec[concat_25-ssl-ca.eclectic.vm.conf] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: Finished catalog run in 18.24 seconds
```

My puppet file

```
# execute 'apt-get update'
exec { 'apt-update':
  command => 'apt-get update',
  path    => ["/usr/bin"],
}

# Install and configure apache2

class { 'apache':                # use the "apache" module
  default_vhost => false,        # don't use the default vhost
  default_mods => false,         # don't load default mods
  mpm_module => 'prefork',        # use the "prefork" mpm_module
  service_ensure => 'running',
}

include apache::mod::php
include apache::mod::rewrite

# Enable not define apache mods
# https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache#defined-type-apachemod
apache::mod { 'access_compat': }

# http eclectic version
apache::vhost { 'com.domain.vm':
  port        => '80',
  docadmin     => '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/public_html',
  override    => ['all'],
  serveraliases => [
    'www.com.domain.vm',
  ],
}

# https eclectic version
apache::vhost { 'ssl-com.domain.vm':
  servername  =>  'com.domain.vm',
  port        => '443',
  docadmin     => '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/public_html',
  override    => ['all'],
  ssl         => true,
  serveraliases => [
    'www.com.domain.vm',
  ],
}

# Setting up custom web eclectic direcotry
file { [
    "/var/www",
    "/var/www/vhosts",
    "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com"
  ]:
  ensure => "directory",
  owner  => "www-data",
  group  => "vagrant",
  mode   => 775,
}


# Add virtual host domain in /etc/hosts
host { 'com.domain.vm':
  ensure => present,
  ip => '127.0.0.1',
  host_aliases => 'www.com.domain.vm',
}


# install mysql-server package
package { 'mysql-server':
  require => Exec['apt-update'],        # require 'apt-update' before installing
  ensure => installed,
}

# ensure mysql service is running
service { 'mysql':
  ensure => running,
  require => Package['mysql-server'],
}


$packages = [
  'vim',
  'nano',
  'htop',
  'tree',
  'pv',
  'wget',
  'curl',
  'git',
  'php5',
  'php5-cli',
  'php5-gd',
  'php5-curl',
  'php5-mysql',
  'php5-mcrypt',
]

package { $packages:
  require => Exec['apt-update'],        # require 'apt-update' before installing
  ensure => installed,
}

exec { 'set-mysql-password':
  command => 'mysqladmin -u admin password "admin"',
  path    => ["/usr/bin"],
  logoutput => true,
  unless => 'mysqladmin -uadmin -padmin version',
  require => Service['mysql'],
}

package { 'php-pear':
  require => Exec['apt-update'],        # require 'apt-update' before installing
  ensure => installed,
  notify  => [
    Exec['pear-discover-channel-phing'],
    Exec['pear-install-Console_Table'],
    Exec['pear-install-Console_Color2'],
  ]
}


# http://puppet-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/composer.html#installation
# Install to different destination
class { 'php::composer':
  destination => '/usr/bin/composer',
  notify  => Exec['composer-install-drush']
}

exec { "pear-discover-channel-phing":
  command => "pear channel-discover pear.phing.info",
  path    => ["/usr/bin"],
  logoutput => true,
  unless => 'pear channel-info pear.phing.info',
  require => Package['php-pear'],
  notify  => Exec['pear-install-phing'],
}

exec { "pear-install-phing":
  command => "pear install phing/phing",
  unless => "which phing",
  path    => ["/usr/bin"],
  logoutput => false,
  require => Exec['pear-discover-channel-phing'],
}

exec { "pear-install-Console_Table":
  command => "pear install Console_Table",
  unless => "pear info Console_Table",
  path    => ["/usr/bin"],
  logoutput => true,
}

exec { "pear-install-Console_Color2":
  command => "pear install Console_Color2-0.1.2",
  unless => "pear info Console_Color2-0.1.2",
  path    => ["/usr/bin"],
  logoutput => true,
}


####################################
# Install drush
exec { "git-clone-drush":
  command => "git clone https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git /usr/local/src/drush",
  path    => ["/usr/bin"],
  unless  => 'test -d /usr/local/src/drush',
  notify  => Exec['git-checkout-drush']
}

exec { "git-checkout-drush":
  command => "git checkout 6.6.0",
  cwd     => "/usr/local/src/drush",
  path    => ["/usr/bin"],
  require => Exec['git-clone-drush'],
  notify  => File['/usr/bin/drush']
}

file { "/usr/bin/drush":
  ensure => 'link',
  target => '/usr/local/src/drush/drush',
  require => Exec['git-checkout-drush'],
  notify  => Exec['composer-install-drush']
}

exec { "composer-install-drush":
  environment => [ "COMPOSER_HOME=/usr/local/src/drush" ],
  command => "composer install",
  cwd     => "/usr/local/src/drush",
  path    => ["/usr/bin"],
  require => File['/usr/bin/drush']
}


# Copy ssh config vagrant file
file { '/home/vagrant/.ssh/config':
  ensure => present,
  mode   => 600,
  source => "puppet:///files/ssh/config/default-config",
}
```

Comment: It looks like you might not have ruby installed on Windows: 
Could not evaluate: /usr/bin/env: ruby

Comment: @OverlordAlex nope this is not the issue. I've install ruby and restart command prompt and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably the same as mine, on which I spent the last couple of days. In my case the problem was with the windows **git** program.

When you install git under Windows it asks whether you would like to configure CRLF<->LF conversion - there are 3 options:

1. default, **Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings** - that means convert LF to CRLF when checking out, and convert CRLF to LF when committing,
2. **Checkout as-is, commit Unix-style line encodings** - do not convert on check-out, and convert CRLF to LF when committing,
3. **Checkout as-is, commit as-is** - do not convert at all.

At first I chose (1), so git converted LF to CRLF when checking out one of the modules, **icinga-vagrant\modules\concat**, and specifically the script file **icinga-vagrant\modules\concat\files\concatfragments.rb**. The script then would be copied (without conversion) to the target Linux virtual machine, and wouldn't run there because /usr/bin/env didn't understand what "ruby<CR>" meant, and that's why the error message had a newline in it:

```
... Could not evaluate: /usr/bin/env: ruby
: No such file or directory
```

**The resolution was to reinstall git with option nr (2)**, although it can probably be changed without reinstallation - I was a bit lazy. Now, git checks the script as is, with only LF at line ends, and so runs without problems on Linux.

Comment: You can also just set ``git config --global core.autocrlf input``

Answer (score 0):

Did you include module `stdlib` in puppet? concat is one of functions in it. Can you show me the `Puppetfile` if you manage forge module by `librarian-puppet`

Seems the dependence is the issue. Should fix your issue after install with it.

Comment: Actually I have `stdlib` and `concat` modules. And `puppetfile` is added now in question.